# Is there any way to convert the response body to XML in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a get request in flutter, the response body comes as json, is there any way to have it in XML?
In the Swagger UI it comes as XML but I don't know why it comes as Json in my request.
I am using this lines:

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(selectedURL));
print(response.body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set the `Accept` header to something like:
`Accept: application/xml`

Something like this might do the trick:

```
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(selectedURL),
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
  },
);
print(response.body);
```